# Find Sql parent rows with exactly same set of child rows

Tags: sql, sql-server, left-join

I've got a MS SQL database with orders. There are two tables orers and orderrows. 
I would like to get all orders that have identical orders: that means show orders that have exactly the same products and quantities.

create tables and data:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[orders](
    [orderid] [int] NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO

INSERT INTO orders values(1)
INSERT INTO orders values(2)
INSERT INTO orders values(3)
INSERT INTO orders values(4)

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[orderrows](
    [orderid] [int] NULL,
    [LineNum] [int] NULL,
    [Quantity] [decimal](18, 6) NULL,
    [ItemCode] [nvarchar](20) NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO

INSERT INTO orderrows values(1,0,11.0,'Item1')
INSERT INTO orderrows values(1,1,12.0,'Item2')
INSERT INTO orderrows values(1,2,13.0,'Item3')
INSERT INTO orderrows values(1,3,14.0,'Item4')
INSERT INTO orderrows values(2,0,11.0,'Item1')
INSERT INTO orderrows values(2,1,12.0,'Item2')
INSERT INTO orderrows values(2,2,13.0,'Item3')
INSERT INTO orderrows values(2,3,14.0,'Item4')
INSERT INTO orderrows values(3,0,11.0,'Item1')
INSERT INTO orderrows values(3,1,12.0,'Item2')
INSERT INTO orderrows values(4,0,15.0,'Item5')
INSERT INTO orderrows values(4,1,16.0,'Item6')
```

I've created this query:

```
select t1.orderid, t1.Itemcode, t1.quantity, t1.LineNum, t2.orderid, t2.Itemcode 
FROM orderrows t1
    LEFT OUTER JOIN orderrows t2 ON t1.itemcode = t2.ItemCode and t1.quantity = t2.Quantity and t2.LineNum = t1.linenum
    where t1.orderid <> t2.orderid
    order by t1.orderid, t2.orderid
```

This gives the following results:

[image]

Does anyone know hot to get rid of the crossed out rows? These orders aren't an exact match but have only a subset of the orderrows. e.g. row 5 and 6 show order 3, but this order only has item1 and item2.

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you will need to compare the full set of rows for each order with other full sets. Also, can you clarify that `exactly the same products and quantities` whereas your SqlQuery also uses `LineNum` in the comparison - is an order to be regarded as different if the `LineNums` are switched yet the Order Items and Quantities are the same?

Comment: The definition of "same order" was open for internal debate - We've scrapped LineNum from the comparison. So the solution from @StuartLC is tested and accepted, thanks!

Comment: Adding `LineNum` into the mix is as easy as adding it to 4 x selects, viz `SELECT ItemCode, Quantity, LineNum ...`

Comment: Any solution using linq for the same problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's one approach - build up all combination of orderids, and then using `EXCEPT` to eliminate mismatching orders. I'm assuming `LineNum` isn't relevant to the 'exact' comparison.

```
-- Build up all combinations of orders
WITH orderPairs AS
(
    select o1.orderid as orderid1, o2.orderid as orderid2
    from orders o1
        cross join orders o2
    where 
        o1.orderid > o2.orderid -- prevent self matches, and duplicate checks
)
SELECT *
  FROM orderPairs op
  WHERE 
    NOT EXISTS
    -- All in O1 are in O2
    (SELECT ItemCode, Quantity 
      FROM orderrows orw1 
      WHERE orw1.orderid = op.orderid1 

      EXCEPT 

      SELECT ItemCode, Quantity 
      FROM orderrows orw2 
      WHERE orw2.orderid = op.orderid2)

    AND NOT EXISTS

    -- All in O2 are in O1
    (SELECT ItemCode, Quantity 
     FROM orderrows orw2 
      WHERE orw2.orderid = op.orderid2

      EXCEPT 

      SELECT ItemCode, Quantity 
      FROM orderrows orw1 
      WHERE orw1.orderid = op.orderid1 )
```

This isn't necessarily the most efficient way to do this (e.g. early row counts could avoid the line by line matching)

[SqlFiddle here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/bd795/1), viz indicating that `Order1` and `Order2` are identical.

Comment: Any solution using linq for the same problem?

Comment: @suraj13k that's a different question entirely (this is purely a SQL question) - you'll need to ask a new question, if you've already done an exhaustive search for set comparison in LINQ. But LINQ's `.Except(), All() and .Contains()` extensions should be enough to get you to an answer.

Comment: Yeah, I will ask a question if I don't get it. I have done that using All(), Any() and Where() extensions.